# Firefox address grey / blacked out - Google Chromium black square over links

Tags: firefox, chromium

[image: Black squares ![][1]]Similar questions have been asked, but I have not found answer that works for me. This problem started a few weeks ago, but I have not been able to recall what had changed. The only changes I have "approved" are the Ubuntu Updates.

In Firefox, the address bar is in grey and black boxes where text should be, highlighting whites out everything leaving an orange line across top. In Chromium, the black square appears over the links in the upper right portion of page. There is also some cobalt blue text that can be seen in that square.

Thanks for any suggestions you might have.

### Specifications:

---

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

IBM S50 Thinkcentre Desktop

---

### Screenshot(s)

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can we please have a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: I edited your post, and included the screen shots you left at the bottom (unlinked). I do not see the problem exactly. If you ping me (@NoTime to ping me) I can add another screen shot if you include it as a link. Until your rep is higher you will not be able to post screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to be a bug.

> there's a Launchpad Report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1316250. So hopefully there will be progress in solving this bug.
>
> A quick workaround that also worked for me is the following: In Firefox 29: Type about:config [Enter] - Promise to be careful - In the Search Bar type gfx.xrender.enabled - Right-click (F12) and Toggle to make it false -Exit Firefox - Open Firefox again.
>
> Voila.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/998416

Comment: Unable to figure out how to do this in Firefox 31. About:config in the address bar? or someplace else?

Comment: @SerfurSaylor Yes, type about:config into the address bar.  It will let you access firefox's deeper settings that are normally hidden.